# How to input int64_t / uint64_t constants?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, constants, int64

What I'm trying to do is to define a constant equal to 2^30 (I may change it to something like 2^34, so I prefer to have a room larger than 32 bits for it).

Why the following minimal(?) example doesn't compile?

```
#include <stdint.h>
// test.cpp:4:33: error: expected primary-expression before numeric constant
// test.cpp:4:33: error: expected ')' before numeric constant
const uint64_t test = (uint64_t 1) << 30;
//const uint64_t test1 = (uint64_t(1)) << 30;// this one magically compiles! why?

int main() { return 0; }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(uint64_t 1)` is not valid syntax. When casting, you can either use `uint64_t(1)` or `(uint64_t) 1`. The commented out example works because it follows the proper syntax for casting, as would:

```
const uint64_t test = ((uint64_t)1) << 30;
```

Edit: While this directly answers the question, see the [answer by Shafik Yaghmour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22363263/2721883) on how to properly define an integral constant with specific size.

Comment: Yes, you are right. For some reason I forgot the brackets around the type, and they are indeed required for c-like cast notation.

Comment: I usually just use sized literal suffixes
`auto value = 1ui64 << 30;`
(though sadly it appears that only MSVC supports typed suffixes whereas clang, gcc, and Intel compilers only support ULL after trying on Godbolt - oh well)

Answer (score 48):

You can use the macro:

```
UINT64_C
```

to define a 64bit unsigned integer literal, the `cstdint` header provides macros for defining integer literals of specific sizes, we see that in section `18.4.1` *Header  synopsis*:

> The header also defines numerous macros of the form:

and includes:

> plus function macros of the form:
>
> > [U]INT{8 16 32 64 MAX}_C

We have to go back to the  C99 draft standard to find how they work, section `7.18.4.1` *Macros for minimum-width integer constants* which says:

> [...]if uint_least64_t is a name for the type unsigned long long int,
>   then **UINT64_C(0x123) might expand to the integer constant 0x123ULL**.

as the proper way of defining a 64bit integer constant expression. This is unfortunately not document on cpprefernce but [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/) does document this feature for of the `cstdint` header as well as the [posix reference for stdint.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html).

Comment: while not as directly applicable to the OP as the accepted answer, this answer is more generally useful, and should be the accepted answer for that reason.

Comment: I would also include this link for reference : http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html

Comment: @ToddFreed ok, I will take a look at look at that reference. I have received a few upvotes for this recently and I am wondering if this has been linked from some outside site.

Answer (score 17):

The syntax you are looking for is:

```
const uint64_t test = 1ULL << 30;
```

The post-fix `ULL` is used for unsigned integer literals that are at least 64-bits wide.

Comment: Good to know this neat short notation. I would accept your answer too, if I could accept two answers.

Comment: @fiktor This isn't a "short notation", this is *the* notation for writing numeric literals of a specified size.  Using the casting method will end up being optimized to this on the first compiler pass (for any remotely decent compiler).

Comment: This is not correct. If you are using uint64_t to define your integer type, you should use the corresponding literal notation, UINT64_C(arg). The "ULL" suffix corresponds exactly to "unsigned long long", while uint64_t might not, depending on the platform. This kind of platform independence is the only reason you would use uint64_t in the first place.

Comment: @ToddFreed You realize that `UINT64_C` is a macro that expands to `value##ULL`, right?  In other words, it does exactly the same thing I posted here.  Claiming it is "incorrect" is factually wrong.

Comment: On a platform where uint64_t == unsigned long long, UINT64_C will expand to ULL. On a platform where uint64_t == unsigned long, UINT64_C will expand to UL. Please read stdint.h.

Comment: @ToddFreed stdint.h is going to be implementation specific, but every implementation I have installed currently has the same definition.  So, if you want to be VERY specific, you could say that "on some off the wall platform, this might give you a warning as it is down-casting a larger integer to a smaller one", but to say it is "not correct" is inaccurate.  It is actually what `stdint.h` does, in most cases.

Comment: If you only care about platforms where uint64_t == unsigned long long, then your solution works fine. But then, why not use unsigned long long as your data type in the first place? Your initial statement which I was contesting is still wrong, "ULL is for unsigned 64-bit integers". A true statement would be, ULL is for unsigned long long integers.

Comment: `long long int` is required, by the standard, to be *at least* 64-bits.  So, if your complaint is that I didn't specify that, I think you are nit-picking and going well beyond what this question was asking almost 2 years ago.  Additionally, your assertion that the only reason to use the `(u)int(n)_t` types is for platform independence is completely bogus.

Comment: SO to if you want to be safe you'd use the macro like `const uint64_t test = UINT64_C(1) << 30;` ??? ... and this would make it platform independent???