# Best/proper way to define uint64_t constants

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, constants, literals

`constexpr auto v = static_cast<std::uint64_t>(1) << 32;` is not ideal, because of the tedious syntax and the cast which is semantically indirect. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22363263/1348273) thread, I learned `constexpr auto v = UINT64_C(1) << 32;` However, the precise semantics of the [macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) is

> expands to an integer constant expression having the value specified
>   by its argument and the type `uint_least64_t`.

Therefore, it's not exactly `uint64_t`. I'm wondering what is the best/proper way to define `uint64_t` constants.

Note that `unsigned long long` doesn’t necessarily map to `uint64_t`.

**Update**

I'm reluctant to use functional/C-style cast, because some (e.g., Google C++ Coding Style) say it's from C, and modern C++ should avoid using them. Looks like I should have my own opinion on this, instead of blindly following others.

Comment: How about good old:  const uint64_t one = 1ULL;

Comment: Surely this is solved by not using auto? Show me the benefit that `auto` gave you, over simply declaring  `std::uint64_t v = 1;` ?  Anyway, you can decorate your 1 with U and L, to make it unsigned and long.

Comment: @GemTaylor Updated question.

Comment: Why not a function style cast then? `constexpr auto v = std::uint64_t{1} << 32`? Goes hand in hand with Herb Sutter's almost always auto advice.

Comment: @Lingxi: "*Note that unsigned long long doesn’t necessarily map to uint64_t.*" And `uint64_t` doesn't have to be defined by your compiler either, yet your code assumes that it is. I see no difference between that assumption and the assumption that `ULL` is 64-bits. Are there real systems that provide `uint64_t` which *don't* define `ULL` to be 64-bits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Therefore, it's not exactly `uint64_t`. I'm wondering what is the best/proper way to define `uint64_t` constants.

If you want to be absolutely sure, you can write `uint64_t(1)` (possibly `std::`-qualified) instead as a shorter alternative to your `static_cast`.

For practical purposes, `UINT64_C` is fine though. Implementations aren't required to define `uint64_t` if they don't provide any type which meets its requirements. It makes sense because of that to define `UINT64_C` in terms of `uint_least64_t`.

But on implementations where `uint64_t` does exist -- and you're implicitly already assuming you're using such an implementation -- `uint64_t` and `uint_least64_t` must have the exact same range, are it would pretty much require malice on the implementor's part to not make them the exact same type.

P.S. Since this is tagged language-lawyer: there is no guarantee that `uint64_t(1) << 32` still has type `uint64_t`. Hypothetically, an implementation may provide a larger-than-64-bit `int` type, in which case `uint64_t` would be promoted to `int`.

Comment: I'm somewhat restrained from using functional style cast, because some say it's from C, and modern C++ should avoid using it (like Google's C++ Coding Style). In practice, I find functional style and C-style casts quite convenient and elegant in certain contexts. I guess I'm going to have my own opinion on this instead of blindly following others.

Answer (score -2):

There are specifiers for exactly this, using `L` makes your integer literal a `long`, `LL` a `long long` and `ULL` an `unsigned long long`, or, `uint64_t` (most of the time).

Or just drop `auto` all together and just let the compiler make the implicit cast.

Comment: Nowhere is it a fact that `ULL` maps unconditionally to `std::uint64_t`.

Comment: @rubenvb Meant to add that

Comment: While `LL`/`ULL` will work in most cases for 64-bit literals, `L`/`UL` will likely break across different systems since Windows still uses 32-bit `long`s.