# How to define uint64_t constant?

Tags: c++, c++14, qt-creator

I have the uint64_t constants in my C++ program (clang 6.0.1 in QtCreator 4.6.1).

For example:

```
uint64_t a = 0xffffffffffffffffULL;
```

The problem is, that I get the following warning in the IDE:

```
Warning: implicit conversion from 'unsigned long long' to 'uint64_t' (aka 'unsigned long')
```

I tried also to change it to the following without success :

```
uint64_t a = UINT64_C(0xffffffffffffffff);
uint64_t a = 0xffffffffffffffffUL;
```

I have options to compute with C++14 standard and option: `-Wconstant-conversion`

Checking the types size:

```
std::cout << "uint64_t " << sizeof (uint64_t) << std::endl; 
std::cout << "unsigned long " << sizeof (unsigned long) << std::endl;
std::cout << "unsigned long long " << sizeof (unsigned long long) << std::endl;
```

Result:

```
uint64_t 8  
unsigned long 8
unsigned long long 8
```

Any idea how to fix this and why IDE thinks that size conversion is happening?

Edit: I just checked the macro expansion:

```
define UINT64_C(c)  c ## UL
```

This means that provided example should work, however it doesn’t:

```
uint64_t a = 0xffffffffffffffffUL;
```

Comment: The answer is in your warning message! Read it carefully.

Comment: Possibly related: [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48909995/best-proper-way-to-define-uint64-t-constants/48910449), [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363102/how-to-input-int64-t-uint64-t-constants)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Yes I tried. Updated the question with example. No the answer is not in the warning.

Comment: @Ross Congratulations. You're working with a 64 bit architecture.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, 64 bit with LP64/IPL64 data model: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models. Native windows uses LLP64 an UL suffix will be not portable between LP64 and LLP64 models

Comment: Ross, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/22363263/196561 for `UINT64_C` macro from `<cstdint>` header.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, it is 64bit. What is your point?

Comment: @osgx If you read carefully the question, you can see I have already tried this.

Comment: What warnings do you get with the two alternatives that didn't work?

Comment: @hvd The warnings are the same: Warning: implicit conversion from 'unsigned long long' to 'uint64_t' (aka 'unsigned long')

Comment: @Ross, Please provide complete minimal example of code (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), command of clang++ to compile the example outside the IDE and project settings of QTC to get hints about how it may start clang++. With https://godbolt.org/ and my example I can't get clang++ 6 to print any warning for UINT64_C.

Comment: @Ross If your compiler sees `0xffffffffffffffffUL` as an `unsigned long long` constant (since you say the error still says "conversion from 'unsigned long long'"), then your `unsigned long` type doesn't have 64 bits. If your headers nonetheless define `uint64_t` as `unsigned long`, then something is seriously wrong. Are you somehow accidentally using another platform's headers? That doesn't match the test program's output, though.

Comment: @hvd This indeed seems to be problem with mixed headers. I tried to copy the definition in another file and the warning is not shown in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This warning is resolved thanks to @hvd comment.

Checked all included header files. For some reason, both `stdint.h` and `cstdint` were included. I left only the `cstdint`. They are probably from different platforms and have different definitions.

The working example:

```
uint64_t v0 = UINT64_C(0x736f6d6570736575);
```

Comment: Macros are evil - and hardly ever needed.

Comment: What happens if only `stdint.h` included? Or if only `cstdint`? Presumably, for one of these cases, you'll get the same bogus warning (it should not be a problem, if both included). "They are probably from different platforms and have different definitions.": this means that your installation is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

`unsigned long long` is at least 64 bits, so it could be a bigger type than `uint64_t`

I would write (note the use of constexpr because it's a constant):

```
#include <cinttypes>
#include <limits>
constexpr auto a = std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::max();
```

And to define a non-max `uint64_t` constant in portable way, just remove the `ULL` part at the end:

```
constexpr std::uint64_t b = 0x12345;
```

Comment: Equal or bigger. 64 bits, not bytes. Depending on data model: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models. How to define non-max constant in portable way?

Comment: @bit_data_models nice catch for bytes -> bits. What do you mean by Equal or bigger? I said "at least" in my answer, which is the same as equal or bigger. No?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is warning you of an *implicit* conversion between types that are not guaranteed to be of the same size in C++. A possible fix is to make it explicit:

```
uint64_t a = static_cast<uint64_t>(0xffffffffffffffffULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it :

```
auto a = static_cast<uint64_t>(-1);
```

Answer (score -1):

The first thing to note here is that you don't need the `LL` suffix.

An integer literal automatically will have a type which can hold the number. Check out [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.icon#2) table for exact types. The only exception to this rule is if you specify a decimal literal which only fits to `unsigned long long int`. Then you need to specify the `u` suffix.

Now, the warning can be removed easily with a cast:

`uint64_t a = (uint64_t)0xffffffffffffffff;`

or if you don't like C cast, then with `static_cast`:

`uint64_t a = static_cast<uint64_t>(0xffffffffffffffff);`

---

So far, this was the theory, but you have some problems with your compiler/installation. If you have the implicit conversion warning for this:

`uint64_t a = 0xffffffffffffffffUL;`

where `uint64_t` is `unsigned long`, then it means that `0xffffffffffffffffUL` actually becomes `unsigned long long int`. But it should not be, as `sizeof(unsigned long)` is 8 already. This is clearly an impossible situation, if the compiler and installation is correct.