# Purpose of using UINT64_C?

Tags: c++, macros

I found this line in boost source:

```
const boost::uint64_t m = UINT64_C(0xc6a4a7935bd1e995);
```

I wonder what is the purpose of using a MACRO here?

All this one does is to add `ULL` to the constant provided.

I assume it may be used to make it harder for people to make mistake of typing `UL` instead of `ULL`, but I wonder if there is any other reason to use it.

Comment: Is the macro always defined the same way? There's no define that changes what it might be defined at for different systems / hardware?

Comment: See [How to input int64_t / uint64_t constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22363102/1708801)

Comment: The main point is communication, this is an unsigned 64-bit constant. It is redundant in the context of initializing a `uint64_t` but perhaps they have a policy of always using `UINT64_C` on what are meant to be uint64_t constants in other contexts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you look at [boost/cstdint.h](https://github.com/boostorg/config/blob/master/include/boost/cstdint.hpp), you can see that the definition of the `UINT64_C` macro is different on different platforms and compilers.

On some platforms it's defined as `value##uL`, on others it's `value##uLL`, and on yet others it's `value##ui64`.  It all depends on the size of `unsigned long` and `unsigned long long` on that platform or the presence of compiler-specific extensions.

I don't think using `UINT64_C` is actually necessary in that context, since the literal `0xc6a4a7935bd1e995` would already be interpreted as a 64-bit unsigned integer.  It is necessary in some other context though.  For example, [here](https://github.com/boostorg/log/blob/master/src/timestamp.cpp#L88) the literal `0x00000000ffffffff` would be interpreted as a 32-bit unsigned integer if it weren't specifically specified as a 64-bit unsigned integer by using `UINT64_C` (though I think it would be promoted to `uint64_t` for the bitwise AND operation).

In any case, explicitly declaring the size of literals where it matters serves a valuable role in code-clarity.  Sometimes, even if an operation is perfectly well-defined by the language, it can be difficult for a human programmer to tell what types are involved.  Saying it explicitly can make code easier to reason about, even if it doesn't directly alter the behavior of the program.

Comment: Is this necessary when dealing with integer literals though, as `uint64_t` will be the correct size anyway? Will the compiler on certain platforms complain if it encounters an unannotated integer literal that needs annotation?

Comment: It is basically giving a hint to the compiler so it does not have to guess what type is required and then correct it later.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary in this context, but there are places it's needed.  [Here](https://github.com/boostorg/log/blob/master/src/timestamp.cpp#L88), for example, I believe `0x00000000ffffffff` would be an unsigned 32-bit type if `UINT64_C` weren't used (though I think it would get promoted to `uint64_t` for the bitwise AND operation).  There were a lot of "I think"s in this comment though, which just proves the usefulness of this macro as a code-clarity aid.

Comment: @MilesBudnek: Hmm, isn't it the case, that even the whole `& UINT64_C(0x00000000ffffffff)` not needed there? Just a cast would be sufficient, wouldn't it? And even, if `UINT64_C` wasn't there, the expression would be the same?

Comment: funny, i never knew borland was so broken... but then again it is source file that is 20 y old :)