# What is the difference between using INTXX_C macros and performing type cast to literals?

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion, integer, stdint

For example this code is broken (I've just fixed it in actual code..).

```
uint64_t a = 1 << 60
```

It can be fixed as,

```
uint64_t a = (uint64_t)1 << 60
```

but then this passed my brain.

```
uint64_t a = UINT64_C(1) << 60
```

I know that `UINT64_C(1)` is a macro that expands usually as `1ul` in 64-bit systems, but then what makes it different than just doing a type cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(uint64_t)1` is formally an `int` value `1` casted to `uint64_t`, whereas `1ul` is a constant `1` of type `unsigned long` which is probably the same as `uint64_t` on a 64-bit system. As you are dealing with constants, all calculations will be done by the compiler and the result is the same.

The macro is a portable way to specify the correct suffix for a constant (literal) of type `uint64_t`. The suffix appended by the macro (`ul`, system specific) can be used for literal constants only.

The cast `(uint64_t)` can be used for both constant and variable values. With a constant, it will have the same effect as the suffix or suffix-adding macro, whereas with a variable of a different type it may perform a truncation or extension of the value (e.g., fill the higher bits with 0 when changing from 32 bits to 64 bits).

Whether to use `UINT64_C(1)` or `(uint64_t)1` is a matter of taste. The macro makes it a bit more clear that you are dealing with a constant.

As mentioned in a comment, `1ul` is a `uint32_t`, not a `uint64_t` on windows system. I expect that the macro `UINT64_C` will append the platform-specific suffix corresponding to `uint64_t`, so it might append `uLL` in this case. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/52490273/10622916.

Comment: `1ul` is a `uint32_t`, not a `uint64_t` on windows systems :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no obvious difference or advantage, these macros are kind of redundant. There are some minor, subtle differences between the cast and the macro:

- `(uintn_t)1` might be cumbersome to use for preprocessor purposes, whereas `UINTN_C(1)` expands into a single pp token.
- The resulting type of the `UINTN_C` is actually `uint_leastn_t` and not `uintn_t`. So it is not necessarily the type you expected.
- Static analysers for coding standards like MISRA-C might moan if you type `1` rather than `1u` in your code, since shifting signed integers isn't a brilliant idea regardless of their size.
  `(uint64_t)1u` is MISRA compliant,  `UINT64_c(1)` might not be, or at least the analyser won't be able to tell since it can't expand pp tokens like a compiler. And `UINT64_C(1u)` will likely not work, since this macro implementation probably looks something like this:

  ```
  #define UINT64_C(n) ((uint_least64_t) n ## ull)
  // BAD: 1u##ull = 1uull
  ```

In general, I would recommend to use an explicit cast. Or better yet wrap all of this inside a named constant:

```
#define MY_BIT ( (uint64_t)1u << 60 )
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that none of the macros would include a cast since as you say, they each produce a single pp token (without any parentheses or anything). `MY_BIT` *could* be defined with `#define MY_BIT (UINT64_C(1) << 60)` if you wanted to use the value for preprocessor purposes.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes well unlike the compiler lib, I can't know which suffix `uint_least64_t` corresponds to, although it's very likely `ull`. Please regard my `UINT64_C` macro here as pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

`UINT64_C(1)` produces a single token via token pasting, whereas `((uint64_t)1)` is a constant expression with the same value.

They can be used interchangeably in the sample code posted, but not in preprocessor directives such as `#if` expressions.

`XXX_C` macros should be used to define constants that can be used in `#if` expressions. They are only needed if the constant must have a specific type, otherwise just spelling the constant in decimal or hexadecimal without a suffix is sufficient.