# `LL` vs `i64` suffix in C++ Visual Studio compiler

Tags: c++, c++17, 64-bit, literals, int64

I'm trying to refactor an old C++ code. At some point I've something like:

```
#if defined(WIN32) && !(defined(__CYGWIN__) || defined(__MINGW32__))
#  define I64_CONST(X)  X ## i64
#else
#  define I64_CONST(X)  X ## LL
#endif
```

So for defining a 64-bit literal in the code there's something like:

```
(uint32_t)((data_in >> 32) & I64_CONST(0x00000000ffffffff));
```

This is for using `i64` suffix with Microsoft compilers and `LL` with other ones. Since I'm adapting it for C++17 and the minimum requirement that we have is to use Visual Studio 2019, is it possible to remove this and use `LL` everywhere, or is there some issue and it's better to maintain the distinction between compilers?

Comment: I think, for some time now, the C++ Standard has required `long long int` to be at least 64 bits wide.

Comment: @AdrianMole is correct.  a `long long` is going to be at least 64 bits wide, but it could be wider.  If you want a standard 64 bit wide type, use `std::int64_t`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `long long` is a [new type since C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) which contains at least 64 bits, so it can be used for your literals (unless the source code is using two's complement and the compiler is using one's complement/sign-magnitude then -2<sup>63</sup> won't fit)

Another way is to use the `INT64_C` in [`<cstdint>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) which was also introduced in C++11

```
#define I64_CONST INT64_C
auto v = INT64_C(0xFFFF0000FFFF0000);
```

See [Purpose of using UINT64_C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52490211/995714)

Comment: There's really no need for macro's anymore. The target is VS2019/C++17. Any compiler which can handle that will also support C++11 `long long`. There's no need for 64 bit hacks in this century.

Comment: @PaulSanders obviously not. It redefines a project macro to a standard macro to avoid modifying the whole code. But

Comment: @MSalters of course it's not necessary. It's just a standard alternative