# How to use auto keyword to assign a variable of type uint32_t or uint64_t in C++

Tags: c++11

Consider `auto var = 5u;`. Here, I am using suffix `u`, so that var will be deduced as `unsigned int`. Is there any way to achieve something similar for `uint32_t` or `uint64_t` types? Is there any suffix in C++11 or C++14?

Comment: No, there is no such thing. Spelling out the type is your option. Or define your own literal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to input int64\_t / uint64\_t constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363102/how-to-input-int64-t-uint64-t-constants)

Comment: If you know exactly what type you want, why use auto?

Answer (score 15):

I'm assuming you're working with the [AAA style](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) suggested by Herb Sutter.

In that case, a nice solution is to simply write:

```
auto variable_name = uint64_t{ 5000000000 };
```

This is clear, consistent, and explicitly typed with no nasty C-preprocessor necessary.

---

Edit: if you want to be absolutely sure when using a literal, [an appropriate suffix](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) can be added to the integer literal to ensure great enough range, while still explicitly typing the variable.

Comment: Try an initializer bigger than `2^32`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin the literal can automatically go up to `long long int`, but `unsigned long long int` does require the `u` suffix.

Comment: Will downvoters please comment to explain? I believe this demonstrably works for numbers out of the 32-bit range.

Comment: I imagine the down votes are due to it being easier (less typing) to not use auto at all.

Comment: @nate maybe true, but my answer isn't advocating for this style, it's simply answering the question which is about this style

Answer (score 4):

You could always define your own suffix

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

uint32_t operator ""_u32 (unsigned long long v) { return uint32_t (v); } 

int main ()
{
    auto v = 10_u32;

    static_assert (std::is_same <decltype (v), uint32_t>::value);
}
```